# error in SSA matrix creation

Tags: matlab, matrix, time-series

i would like to  consider  following matlab code

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8115-singular-spectrum-analysis-smoother/content/ssa.m

especially part

```
Step1 : Build trayectory matrix

   N=length(x1); 
   if L>N/2;L=N-L;end
    K=N-L+1; 
   X=zeros(L,K);  
    for i=1:K
      X(1:L,i)=x1(i:L+i-1); 
    end
```

but when i  test on this  data

```
>> x1=[1;3;2;4;5;6;7;8;9];
>> L=5;
>> N=length(x1); 
   if L>N/2;L=N-L;end
    K=N-L+1; 
   X=zeros(L,K);  
    for i=1:K
      X(1:L,i)=x1(i:L+i-1); 
    end
>> X

X =

     1     3     2     4     5     6
     3     2     4     5     6     7
     2     4     5     6     7     8
     4     5     6     7     8     9

>>
```

but it does not seems ok,because there is more data length  6 instead of 5 horizontally,so how can i fix it?how should i make sure that other part is also ok?thanks for helping

EDITED:
code should does following example

```
x1=[2 1 4 3 6 5 8 7];
>> X=create_matrix1(x1,5)

X =

     2     1     4     3     6
     1     4     3     6     5
     4     3     6     5     8
     3     6     5     8     7
```

Comment: That is how the code you showed works when the length of the vector is odd. Just look at the line `if L>N/2;L=N-L;end; K=N-L+1;` when N=9 and L=5, then K ends up 6.

Comment: but if length  is even?

Comment: no no L should be horizontal length

Comment: First, `L` is modified before it is used, so it is no longer 5 by the time the X is created.  If you don't want it to be, get rid of the line that modifies it.  Second, `X(1:L, i)` refers to a column, not a row.